# What is (special in) the elf format for static-pie? And what preforms the fixups to the GOT?

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux, elf, mmu

I'm trying to create some static-pie programs to run in a no-MMU environment.

As far as I can tell static-pie programs are encoded in the ELF format, but use the ET_DYN  e_type in their ELF header.  However, they are not dynamically linked.  They are statically linked.  So how is that encoded into the ELF header?  The Kernel would need to know that during load.

Furthermore, I would expect the Linux Kernel to preform the fix-ups to the Global Offset Table (GOT) since we are not using a dynamic loader, but I want to confirm this?

There seems to be very little good information on this from normal searches and I'm not sure what manuals to be looking at.  Thank you.

Comment: Not much information around, this seems to be a decent summary: https://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/2015/06/01/12

Comment: ^- kernel doesn't do anything special (ET_DYN + no PT_INTERP), some preparatory work is done in a specialized `rcrt1.o` startup code inside the new process

Comment: *And what preforms the fixups to the GOT?* Yes, the libc does the fixup.  It can be either in the 'entry' assembler or more commonly in the '.init' sections that run before main.  The answer will depend on tool setup and libc.  If something else does the fixup, it is not **static**.  The kernel may now about PIE, but only for stack traces, signals and debugging... but probably not.  GDB, etc need to know.

Comment: @artlessnoise It would seem to me that the kernel would at least need to know enough to not try to run the dynamic linker.

Comment: I need to do more research on implementations and probably write my own simple version to understand this, but it would seem to me that if the libc does the fix-ups to the GOT, it means that the loadable memory segments and sections must keep their offsets to each other when the kernel loads them.  Otherwise, it would have no idea where they are.

Comment: Yes, you asked in the context of the GOT.   The kernel either uses a loader (ld.so) or it runs the start address.  PIE can be contiguous like a binary image.  Then the sections do not matter.  It depends on your goal.  If it is address randomization and you want to make BSS/data/code/rodata distances separate, then you might need extra machinery.  By default GOT/PLT make some assumptions about layout.  Some designs use a single code with multiple data (shared static libraries as an example).  Other applications have multiple code addresses with single data (updates in flash with common RAM)